# Java поиск по переменной дочернего класса, по дочернему классу

Tags: java, ооп, классы, arraylist

Есть программа, в которой есть несколько классов - типов програмного обеспечения. (Freeware, Shareware, CommercialSoftware). Для всех родительский абстрактный класс - Software
Данные классов берутся из файла и добавляются в различные классы в зависимости от длины строки в файле(длины массива).
Конструкторы классов:

```
public Software(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public FreeWare(String name, String producer, LocalDate installationDate) {
   super(name);
   this.producer = producer;
   this.installationDate = installationDate;
}

public ShareWare(String name, String producer, LocalDate installationDate, LocalDate dateOfUseEnding ) {
    super(name, producer, installationDate);
    this.dateOfUseEnding=dateOfUseEnding;
    
}

public CommercialSoftware(String name, String producer, LocalDate installationDate, LocalDate dateOfUseEnding, double  price) {
    super(name, producer, installationDate, dateOfUseEnding);
    this.price=price;
}
```

Все объекты этих классов добавляются в такой список:

```
public static List<Software> softwares = new ArrayList();
```

Вот таким образом:

```
static{
    try {   
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("software.csv"));
        String title = scanner.nextLine();
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
         
            String[] line = scanner.nextLine().split(";");
            int arrayLength = line.length;
            if(arrayLength==3){
                LocalDate installationDate = LocalDate.parse(line[2]);
                FreeWare freeWare = new FreeWare(line[0],line[1],installationDate);
                softwares.add(freeWare);
            }else if(arrayLength==4){
                LocalDate installationDate = LocalDate.parse(line[2]);
                LocalDate useEndDate = LocalDate.parse(line[3]);
                ShareWare shareWare = new ShareWare(line[0],line[1],installationDate,useEndDate);
                softwares.add(shareWare);
            }else if(arrayLength==5){
                LocalDate installationDate = LocalDate.parse(line[2]);
                LocalDate useEndDate = LocalDate.parse(line[3]);
                CommercialSoftware commercialSoftware = new CommercialSoftware(line[0],line[1],installationDate,useEndDate,Double.parseDouble(line[4].replace(',','.')));
                softwares.add(commercialSoftware);
            }else{
                System.out.println("ERROR!");
            }
        } 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

Мне нужно осуществить поиск по этому списку. Поиск по имени не составил проблем, так как данная переменная есть в главном классе.

Вопрос 1:
Мне нужно сделать поиск по производителю(producer), но этой переменной нет в главном классе, который является типом данных для списка. Как это сделать?

Вопрос 2:
Нужно сделать поиск по типу софта. Как сделать поиск по названию дочернего класса, чтобы не добавлять лишнюю переменную для типа софта.

**Пример поиска:**

```
//poisk po chasti nazvanija
public static List<Software> searchByPartOfTheName(String partOfTheName){
    List<Software> search = new ArrayList();
    for(Software soft:softwares){ 
    if(soft.getName().contains(partOfTheName))           
    {
        search.add(soft);          
    }       

    return search;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас список softwares

Если проверять тип каждого элемента

```
if(software instanceof FreeWare){...}
```

Можно перебирать и находить обратно то что добавили в список. Почитайте подробнее об [instanceof](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/2018-kak-rabotaet-operator-instanceof)

Не большой пример

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

abstract class Software {}

class FreeSoftware extends Software {
  Boolean free = true;
}

class ShareWareSoftware extends Software {
  Boolean shareWare = true;
}

class CommercialSoftware extends Software {
  Boolean commercial = true;
}

public class App {

  // Driver code
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    List<Software> softwares = new ArrayList<Software>();

    softwares.add(new FreeSoftware());
    softwares.add(new ShareWareSoftware());
    softwares.add(new ShareWareSoftware());
    softwares.add(new CommercialSoftware());

    for (Software software : softwares) {
      if (software instanceof FreeSoftware) {
        System.out.println(((FreeSoftware) software).free);
        if (software.getClass().getName().contains("FreeSoftware")) {
          System.out.println(software.getClass().getName());
        }
      }

      if (software instanceof ShareWareSoftware) {

        System.out.println(((ShareWareSoftware) software).shareWare);
        if (software.getClass().getName().contains("ShareWareSoftware")) {
          System.out.println(software.getClass().getName());
        }
      }

      if (software instanceof CommercialSoftware) {
        System.out.println(((CommercialSoftware) software).commercial);
        if (software.getClass().getName().contains("CommercialSoftware")) {
          System.out.println(software.getClass().getName());
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Извините, а можно ли передать класс в функцию в качестве переменной?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь вводил название класса...

Comment: Добавила, как примерно у меня осуществлен поиск

Comment: Да конечно почему нет?

Comment: Так можно делать если вы заранее знаете сколько у вас классов и все эти классы вы пишите сами, но если эти классы вы будете получать к примеру от другой системы после десериализации, то лучше так не делать, если классов много то и проверок будет много, тогда лучше почитать что такое интерфейс, и проверять его наличие и приводить переменную к типу интерфейса.

Comment: Просто, какого типа должна быть переменная в таком случае? Строку передать не дает, говорит что нельзя, строка не является классом.

Comment: Извине, я не могу использовать интерфейс, так как это домашка и нужно использовать абстрактный класс.